# Help with animation Minecraft rig

Tags: animation, rigging

There was a problem with the texture of the character when moving it. The fact is that when you try to move the character along the Z coordinate, the texture of the character changes, and his head becomes monochromatic with the hair color, while the eyes remain on the layer with the head. Could the problem be related to texture binding, or is it something else?
(I would like to add that with the standard position of the character, everything looks as it should)

rig i use for animation is ThomasRig
[image]

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Blender SE! That's not really a lot of information to go on so your question might not get answered as it is. If you [upload](https://blend-exchange.com/) your file with the textures [packed](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/packed_data.html) someone can take a look at it for you. Right now, it seems really unlikely that the UV mapping is the issue, as those usually apply to an object based on its own local coordinate. I would take a look at the rig weighting itself. Are you getting other artifacts like z-fighting or smooth shading?

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.